# How to install redis modules to AWS elasticache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

Basically, we know ElastiCache in AWS is using either MemCached or Redis. We picked up Redis, and found a module potentially useful for us. Is there a way we can install the module to our ElastiCache instance?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since elasticache is a managed service, you can't access the actual redis server to install/load modules. You can only connect to it through clients to run redis commands. The AWS Elasticache [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/elasticache/) does not mention any support for modules. So, it looks like it isn't possible. You'll have to use EC2 instance to run your own redis server to use modules till Amazon adds support for modules in elasticache.

Comment: Note: Redis modules are a v4 feature, and v4 has yet to be officially released. Once it is, I expect we'll see at least some Redis-as-a-Service providers support the new version in general, and modules specifically.

Comment: I think AWS cannot directly support redis modules on Elasticcache due to open source license changed by Redis Labs.

https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-labs-modules-license-changes/

Comment: I wrote a blog post on this topic and how to set up your own EC2 instance to do it instead: https://pfisterer.dev/posts/aws-redisgraph-instance -- in case it helps anyone.

Comment: AWS now supports RedisJson, but no other modules yet.