# Can I run RediSearch on a separate server then redis?

Tags: redis, redisearch

Originally was trying to install RediSearch ontop of Aws ElastiCache but it seems they dont support modules in their managed service (makes sense).

Then I was looking into running RediSearch on a separate EC2 instance with my VPC instance that would allow me to utilize it while not having to install it in ElastiCache directly.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? Did you use your own instance and build redis-server and redisearch module? Similar too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690615/how-to-install-redis-modules-to-aws-elasticache/66619800#66619800

Comment: We ended up migrating to Redis Enterprise Cloud :) We cant do this on AWS managed service - I ended up filing a ticket with AWS and they said we couldnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/) is available as a service on [Redis Enterprise Cloud](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/pricing/) from Redis Labs on AWS, Azure and GCP.