# How do I install RediSearch into AWS ElastiCache or Amazon MemoryDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, redisearch, amazon-memory-db

Is it possible to [install RediSearch](https://developer.redis.com/howtos/moviesdatabase/install/) (Redis Module) either in AWS ElastiCache or MemoryDB?
Creating inverted indexing manually can be a real pain and it would be nice to have this feature available in AWS.
I've found a [possible workaround to install it using EC2](https://pfisterer.dev/posts/aws-redisgraph-instance/) but for a production-oriented usage this solution is not feasible. It would be a lot better to have a managed solution where RediSearch is available.

I see that it would also be possible to have [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/) as a service on [Redis Enterprise Cloud](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/pricing/) from Redis Labs on AWS, Azure and GCP, but I'm wondering if this module can be provided directly in AWS without paying for an additional license. RedisJson should be already available in AWS for instance.

On [this old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66617506/1977778) it was confirmed by AWS support that **in 2021** it was not possible using [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/) out of the box in AWS ElastiCache. Is it still the case in 2023?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible, it's prohibited by the source available license for RediSearch.  You can use the Redis Stack image and run on AWS, or have Redis host a Redis Stack instance for you on the cloud provider of your choice - see https://redis.com/try-free/

Redis Stack License (Redis Source Available License 2.0): https://redis.io/docs/stack/license/

RedisJSON (the module from Redis) is not available on ElastiCache, Amazon has implemented its own API that is compatible with parts of the RedisJSON API.